# Typescript generics using class constructor that extends another class with static property inside a factory function

Tags: typescript, generics

Trying to extend a class with a static property, but I'm getting the following type error:

`Property 'property' does not exist on type 'new (...args: any[]) => T'.(2339)`

```
class A {
    static property = 'a'
}

class B extends A {}

function factory<T extends A>(type: new (...args: any[]) => T): T {
    if (type.property) { // error -> Property 'property' does not exist on type 'new (...args: any[]) => T'.(2339)
        console.log('heyyyyy')
    }

    return new type();
}

const b = factory(B);

console.log(B.property)
```

What must be done for this to work without the type error?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend the answer by @mpstv (and avoid type cast)

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any) => any;

function factory<T extends typeof A & Constructor>(type: T): InstanceType<T> {
  if (type.property) {
    console.log('heyyyyy');
  }

  return new type();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49784147/14132148

Your factory will look like:

```js
function factory<T extends typeof A>(type: T): InstanceType<T> {
  if (type.property) {
    console.log('heyyyyy');
  }

  return new type() as InstanceType<T>;
}
```