# Describing a Typescript constructor for a class with generic types

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

There's a function I use in testing:

```
export function cast<T>(obj: any, klass: new (...args: any[]) => T): T {
  if (!(obj instanceof klass)) {
    throw new Error(`Not an instance of ${klass.name}: ${obj.constructor.name}`);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

which is used like this.

```
interface I {...}
class C implements I {...};

const i: I = ...;
const c = cast(i, C);
```

However, if I try to use generics, the compiler complains `string` in the call.

```
interface I<T> {...}
class C<T> implements I {...};

const i: I<string> = ...;
const c = cast(i, C<string>);
                    ~~~~~~
```

`Type 'any' has no signatures for which the type argument list is applicable. ts(2635)`

Any thoughts on how I can make a version of cast that is friendly to generics? Even if it can't verify that instances in `i` are of type `string`, finding a way to get it to compile would be useful (otherwise I have to use `as` anyway.)

[TypeScript cast type using generics and constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784027/typescript-cast-type-using-generics-and-constructor) looks close, but seems bound to a specific type hierarchy.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this [TS Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/N5PkZw). Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (IE providing a playground link would be best).

Comment: I'm using Typescript 4.4.4 and with a small change, the [minimal example](https://tsplay.dev/m047am) fails to compile. So whatever it is, has changed in between.

Specifically, changing from 4.6.4 to 4.7.4 removes the error.

Comment: This is because of the Instantiation expression pattern added in TS4.7.0 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607.  C<string> fails to compile because before 4.7 there was no support to instantiate generic functions/classes with a specific type parameter. Short of upgrading version, there isn't really a terse or compact workaround (I know of). I have done a workaround for instantiation expressions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71670082/17954209), but for functions, and it may or may not be of any use.

Comment: That sounds about right. Thanks. I'm prevented from upgrading due to downstream dependencies. In the meantime you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

Requires Instantiation expression pattern added in TS4.7.0 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607. `C<string>` fails to compile because before 4.7 there was no support to instantiate generic functions/classes with a specific type parameter. Short of upgrading version, there isn't really a terse or compact workaround (I know of). I have done a workaround for instantiation expressions here, but for functions, and it may or may not be of any use.

#### Workaround

You'll have to explicitly declare `C<string>` as the generic parameter.

```js
const c = cast<C<string>>(i, C)
```

Or you can create an instantiator function (although this will only work on class C)

```js
export const I = <T>(
  Base: new (...args: any[]) => C<T>
) => { 
  return Base
}

export const CString = I<string>(C)

const c = cast(i, I<string>(C))
const c2 = cast(i, CString)
```